# JavaFX TableView: Select the whole TableColumn and get the index

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

Assume that we have a simple Tableview with 3 columns (A, B, C). Each Column contains some data which is not important at the moment.

I wondered if it would be possible to make only a whole column selectable (no matter where the user clicks in the column) and retrieve the ID and/or index of that column selected by the user?

For example, the user clicks somewhere in the area of column B. In that case the whole column should be marked and index 2 should be returned.

Any help would be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

table.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, (event) -> {
    if(event.isShortcutDown() || event.isShiftDown())
        event.consume();
});


table.getFocusModel().focusedCellProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {

    if(newVal.getTableColumn() != null){
        table.getSelectionModel().selectRange(0, newVal.getTableColumn(), table.getItems().size(), newVal.getTableColumn());
        System.out.println("Selected TableColumn: "+ newVal.getTableColumn().getText());
        System.out.println("Selected column index: "+ newVal.getColumn());
    }
});

table.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, (event) -> {
    if(event.isShortcutDown() || event.isShiftDown())
        event.consume();
});
```

This snippet:

- sets the [`selectionModeProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MultipleSelectionModel.html#selectionModeProperty) of the selection model of the `TableView` to `SelectionMode.MULTIPLE` to make the `TableView` able to select more than one row.
- sets the [`cellSelectionEnabledProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableSelectionModel.html#cellSelectionEnabledProperty) of the selection model of the `TableView` to to `true` to make the `TableView` able to select cells rather than rows
- attaches a listener to the [`focusedCellProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.TableViewFocusModel.html#focusedCellProperty) of the [focus model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#focusModelProperty--) of the `TableView` which listener prints the `TableColumn` of the currently selected cell and selects all of the cell in the selected column
- consumes the mouse events on the `TableView` if a modifier key is pressed to disable for example *Shift + Click* selection

Comment: wow... works fine. You just saved a whole day for me. Just one question: How would i implement a multi select on columns. e.g keep col A selected when i click on col C?

Comment: The third argument of `selectRange` should be `table.getItems().size() - 1`. It will work without the `-1`, but only sometimes, and the rest of the time it will silently fail. I do not understand how it determines which one to do.