# How to Get JavaFX tableview data and save to Mysql Database

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, tableview, fxml

I have created a table in FXML with javafx , This connects to my database and populates values, I also have two drop downs in them , After selecting the drop down values, I have created a button in the same Column. I need to save the already populated values and the dropdown values into another database. Is there a way to do that.

I have attached an image of the tableview and the controls.

I want to press the "Just Save it" Button. On Button press I want the column data from the corresponding button column to be saved to database.

[image]

```
package javafxapplication4;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javafx.application.HostServices;
    import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
    import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
    import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
    import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
    import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
    import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
    import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
    import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
    import javafx.util.Callback;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
    import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;

    /**
     * FXML Controller class
     *
     * @author ammydeen
     */
    public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

        public TableView tableView;
        public TableColumn col_id;
        public TableColumn date_column;
        public TableColumn task_column;
        public TableColumn bs_column;
        public TableColumn cold_column;
        public TableColumn sub_column;
        public TableColumn er_column;
        public TableColumn comp_column;
        ObservableList<Record> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        @FXML
        public TableColumn error_sub_column;
        @FXML
        private DatePicker fdPicker;
        @FXML
        private DatePicker tdPicker;
        @FXML
        private TextField textFiel;
        public String fromDate;
        public String toDate;
        public String User_Id;
        public Hyperlink hyperlink;
        public ResultSet rs;
        public Connection conn;
        public WebView ewv;

        public WebEngine engine1;

        public ListView listView;

        public HostServices hos;
        @FXML
        public Label hiddenlable;
        @FXML
        private Button bluebutton;
        @FXML
        private Button coldbutton;

        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

            tableView.setEditable(true);

            tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue observableValue, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                    //Check whether item is selected and set value of selected item to Label
                    if (tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
                        TableView.TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = tableView.getSelectionModel();
                        ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
                        TablePosition tablePosition = (TablePosition) selectedCells.get(0);
                        Object val = tablePosition.getTableColumn().getCellData(newValue);
                        hiddenlable.setText((String) val);
                    }
                }
            });

            tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
            tableView.setSortPolicy((param) -> {
                return null; //To change body of generated lambdas, choose Tools | Templates.
            });

            bluebutton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                    try {

                        String utt = hiddenlable.getText();
                        try {
                            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("https://www.google.com"));
                        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(FXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            );
            coldbutton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                    try {

                        String utt = hiddenlable.getText();
                        try {
                            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("www.google.com"));
                        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(FXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            );

        }

        @FXML
        public void onAction(ActionEvent event) {

            LocalDate fDate = fdPicker.getValue();
            LocalDate tDate = tdPicker.getValue();
            fromDate = fDate.toString();
            toDate = tDate.toString();

            User_Id = textFiel.getText();
            System.out.println(User_Id);

            tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
            tableView.setEditable(true);
            data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            String s = "'";
            String d = "'";
            String frDate = s + fromDate + d;
            String trDate = s + toDate + d;
            String uId = s + User_Id + d;

            String query = "SELECT * FROM ecdb.ec_upload WHERE Transcriber_ID = " + uId + " and Date between " + frDate + " AND " + trDate;

            System.out.println(query);
            try {

                String u = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/ecdb";
                String use = "root";
                String pass = "root";

                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(u, use, pass);

                System.out.println("Test1");

                PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    data.add(new Record(rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8)));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error in DB" + e);
            }

            tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
            col_id.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Record, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Record, String> p) {
                    return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(tableView.getItems().indexOf(p.getValue()) + "");
                }
            });

            col_id.setSortable(false);

            date_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("value_0"));

            task_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("value_1"));

            bs_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("value_2"));
            cold_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("value_3"));

            sub_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Trial"));

            er_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Trial"));

            error_sub_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Trial"));

            comp_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("value_4"));

            comp_column.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Record>forTableColumn());

            Callback<TableColumn<Record, String>, TableCell<Record, String>> errorFactory
                    = //
                    new Callback<TableColumn<Record, String>, TableCell<Record, String>>() {
                @Override
                public TableCell call(final TableColumn<Record, String> param) {
                    final TableCell<Record, String> cell = new TableCell<Record, String>() {

                        ObservableList<String> options
                                = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                                        "Option 1",
                                        "Option 2",
                                        "Option 3"
                                );

                        final ComboBox comb = new ComboBox(options);

                        @Override
                        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            if (empty) {
                                setGraphic(null);
                                setText(null);
                            } else {

                                //  System.out.println("This is working");
                                comb.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                                setGraphic(comb);
                                setText(null);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    cell.setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
                    return cell;
                }
            };

            Callback<TableColumn<Record, String>, TableCell<Record, String>> sub_errorFactory
                    = //
                    new Callback<TableColumn<Record, String>, TableCell<Record, String>>() {
                @Override
                public TableCell call(final TableColumn<Record, String> param) {
                    final TableCell<Record, String> cell = new TableCell<Record, String>() {

                        ObservableList<String> options
                                = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                                        "Option 4",
                                        "Option 5",
                                        "Option 6"
                                );

                        public ComboBox comb = new ComboBox(options);

                        @Override
                        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            if (empty) {
                                setGraphic(null);
                                setText(null);
                            } else {
                                String cmb = comb.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();
                                System.out.println(cmb);
                                //System.out.println("This is working");
                                comb.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                                setGraphic(comb);
                                setText(null);
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    cell.setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER;");

                    return cell;
                }
            };

            Callback<TableColumn<Record, String>, TableCell<Record, String>> trialFactory
                    = //
                    new Callback<TableColumn<Record, String>, TableCell<Record, String>>() {
                @Override
                public TableCell call(final TableColumn<Record, String> param) {
                    final TableCell<Record, String> cell = new TableCell<Record, String>() {

                        final Button btn1 = new Button("Just Save It");

                        @Override
                        public void updateItem(String ite, boolean empty) {
                            super.updateItem(ite, empty);
                            if (empty) {
                                setGraphic(null);
                                setText(null);
                            } else {
                                btn1.setOnAction((ActionEvent t)
                                        -> {

                                    int selectdIndex = getTableRow().getIndex();
                                    System.out.println(selectdIndex);

                                    Record selectedRecord = (Record) tableView.getItems().get(selectdIndex);
                                    ObservableList<SubRecord> subDataList
                                            = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                                                    new SubRecord(selectedRecord.getvalue_0(), selectedRecord.getvalue_1(), selectedRecord.getvalue_2(), selectedRecord.getvalue_3(), selectedRecord.getvalue_4()));

                                });
                                btn1.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                                setGraphic(btn1);
                                setText(null);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    cell.setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
                    return cell;
                }
            };

            error_sub_column.setCellFactory(sub_errorFactory);
            er_column.setCellFactory(errorFactory);
            sub_column.setCellFactory(trialFactory);
            tableView.setItems(data);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Just put the code to update the database in the button's `onAction` handler. It's not clear where you are stuck.

Comment: I have done the same, but I don't know how to get that particular columns data onAction of the button in that column.

Comment: Hello @James_D Have you seen the image I uploaded. Please help me out.

Comment: If you can keep up with or retrieve one piece of data like the S.no you can then get the info you need from your database and add the info from the drop down problem. Maybe start here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38012247/javafx-tableview-select-the-whole-tablecolumn-and-get-the-index